# express-handlebars template not loading CSS styling on static routes

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

I have a set of different routes all using the same template `main`, but any route is only one `/` away from the base route applies the CSS but anything beyond that will not include it.

So `app.get('/profile`) will render with the CSS, but `app.get('/profile/edit')` does not.

I am unsure as to why this is not working, as far as I understand this line should apply to all routes set below it.

In server.js

```
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
  //Many different routes
  //...
  //...

    //renders with CSS successfully
    app.get("/profile", (req,res) => {
      res.render('profile', {
        layout: "main",
        cause: {
          title: title
        },
        csrfToken: req.csrfToken
      });
    });

 //this is the route that renders without CSS
    app.get("/profile/edit", (req,res) => {
      res.render('edit', {
        navItems: [
          {name: 'See your fellow supporters',
          link: "/signatures"}
        ],
        layout: "main",
        cause: '',
        csrfToken: req.csrfToken
      });
    });
```

Handlebars templates

```
   //edit.handlebars
    <h2>Change your details</h2>
    <form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="first name">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>

    <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="last name">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>

    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="e-mail">
    <label for="email">E-mail</label>

    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
    <label for="password">Password</label>

    <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="age">
    <label for="age">Age</label>

    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="city/town">
    <label for="city">City or Town</label>

    <input type="text" name="homepage" placeholder="homepage or social media">
    <label for="homepage">Homepage</label>

    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}">
    <input  id="formButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
  </form>


//profile.handlebars
          <h2>Let people know that you support: {{>cause}}</h2>
      <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="age">
        <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="city/town">
        <input type="text" name="homepage" placeholder="homepage or social media">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}"
        <input  id="formButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="continue">
      </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure that in main.handlebars, `style.css` is linked like follows:

```
href="/css/styles.css"
```

and not

```
href="css/styles.css"
```

Answer (score 0):

In `server.js` you can use:

```
app.engine('hbs', expressHandlebars({
 defaultLayout: 'main',
 extname: '.hbs',
 layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'layouts')
}))
```

That would require you to have your `main.hbs` in the `layouts`-folder.

That should fix your problem.